# Convert cURL Command Line to cURL PHP with URL Encoded

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to convert a command line API to PHP cURL

Here's command line php curl

```
curl --data-urlencode "type=5" --data-urlencode "url=https://example.com/test.torrent" --data-urlencode "comment=API test" --data-urlencode "website=https://example.com/" --data-urlencode "apikey=123456-asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf" --data-urlencode "send=true" https://www.source-site.com/get.php
```

This is what I am trying with PHP

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$arr=array(
    'type' => 'category5',
    'url' => 'https://example.com/test.torrent',
    'website' => 'https://example.com',
    'apikey' => '696c1a998ac8f13154-088605f-9b0',
    'send' => 'true'
 );
$data_string = http_build_query($arr);
$ch = curl_init('https://www.source-site.com/get.php'); // this url where my file will be uploaded                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                                                                                                                                         
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
?>
```

Now the problem is, it does not upload the file nor display any errors the page is blank, what's wrong with my PHP codes?

I have updated my codes now I get the following error

```
error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
```

Comment: If you look for errors [curl_error($ch)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) Then maybe you will see them

Comment: You are sending url encoded form data Content-Type, but your data is JSON encoded.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) rather than `json_decode`

Comment: Ok checked the `curl_error($ch)` and `http_build_query` but still page is blank

Comment: in that script you have a syntax error. there's an extra ` );` on the line with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. 

Actually the second argument to that is supposed to be an array of strings

Comment: Yes there was sorry my bad, and now I have updated my codes and I got the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your code and had my own script that echo'd the $_POST array. I `curlopt_custom_request` to `CURLOPT_POST` set to true and added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. I notice that your url has https as well which if your test site doesn't have a cert will cause this to fail you can try setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false for testing, but I didn't have much luck with that. So if that doesn't work maybe try `http://yoursite.com`.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$arr=array(
    'type' => 'category5',
    'url' => 'https://example.com/test.torrent',
    'website' => 'https://example.com',
    'apikey' => '696c1a998ac8f13154-088605f-9b0',
    'send' => 'true'
 );
$data_string = http_build_query($arr);
echo $data_string;
$ch = curl_init('YOUR URL HERE'); // this url where my file will be uploaded
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
$final = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($final);
?>
```

Comment: did you just use http for your url or did https still work? @Ken

Comment: https works with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

and if you think my question was useful so please vote up to my question and thanks once again